# Porting from .net code from windows to linux

Tags: .net, linux, windows, asp.net-core

So i have a webserver coded in .net.Since the advent of .net core,my company has expressed a desire to port from windows to linux .net core. So, is it easy?Is it a two man job? Could i get some useful links in it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried just running via .net core? At least for all of the simple examples I've used with mono, you can just run the .exe via the mono runtime. Unless you're doing some really terrible things, I suspect it will "just work". But ultimately your question is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Did you write a real webserver, i.e. an _alternative_ to IIS? Or did you write a web _service_, i.e. an application running _inside_ IIS?

Comment: Did you make use of many libraries, frameworks or nuget packages which do not have .NET core implementations? This will influence the ease of porting significantly.

Comment: A web server or an application? I did not get your point. There are also open-source web server already available such as nginx. Please clarify your question.

Comment: You're the only person who can tell, we don't know your project and what it uses or how big it is

Comment: Sorry for the vague question ,So what I am porting is a MVC application running on IIS ,I dont have an idea of what all packages are available in .net windows and not in .net core.We dont have any packages specific windows.And we will be using apache instead of IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break down your questions into more specific ones in order to get an idea about the amount of effort a port will need (and increase the chance of more concrete answers at StackOverflow)

Some general thoughts for you to consider:

- ASP.NET Core is a complete new framework. So regardless to Linux/Windows issues you have to bear in mind that there is also the effort to migrate vom e.g. ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC.
- .net Core is a rather young plattform. As more an more libraries will be available for .net Core then porting will be easier. Today it might be difficult to get the right replacement for Windows only libraries. So checking your project dependencies is a major task.

I recommend to plan a fixed timebox for your estimation efforts and try to port a subset of your application in order to get a rough idea. If the result is too much effort then you could plan two steps: First migrate your application to ASP.NET Core running on Windows (and using the full .NET Framework), then replace libraries with .net Core ones (as they will become available) and then do the move to Linux.